# minimal public-key authenticated encryption protocol

Tags: public-key, key-exchange, authenticated-encryption

One party (master) wants to send data to another party (slave) over an insecure channel using public-key encryption and signature schemes such that:

- master is authenticated,
- data is confidential,
- data cannot be replayed.

The minimal assumptions are:

- master has slave's public encryption key,
- slave has master's public verification key,
- the public keys are trusted (how they were obtained is immaterial).

The data can be chosen by master or not (e.g. maybe use a KEM instead of PKE to transmit random data).  I would also like to protect against replay attacks.  For an application, think of remotely (re)setting a key on some device without any pre-shared material; don't want adversary to replay previous exchange.

---

Something like encrypt-then-sign with a nonce:

- master sends request to slave,
- slave generates, stores, and sends nonce $r$ to master,
- master encrypts data $d$ and nonce $c=\texttt{enc}(d\|r)$, signs the ciphertext $\sigma=\texttt{sig}(c)$, and sends both $(c,\sigma)$ to slave,
- slave verifies and decrypts.

Or perhaps sign-then-encrypt with a nonce:

- master sends request to slave,
- slave generates, stores, and sends nonce $r$ to master,
- master signs and encrypts some combination of data and nonce, e.g. $c=\texttt{enc}(d\|\texttt{sig}(d\|r))$, and sends ciphertext to slave,
- slave decrypts and verifies.

---

Coming up with your own protocol is a bad idea, but I can't find a reference fitting my needs.  Can someone give a reference or an outline of such a protocol (asymmetric primitives, one-sided authentication, replay protection)???

---

EDIT: Why not use TLS?  Maybe I should, but I don't know the ins and outs of it.  Some considerations:

- There is no PKI; certificates would be self-signed if used.
- There is no secure Diffie-Hellman I can use.
- I don't *need* mutual authentication.
- Can't use timestamps.
- Don't need baggage like cipher suites etc.

Comment: TLS fits all your requirements. Why don't you want to use it?

Comment: And if TLS somehow didn't work for you, there's almost certainly a [Noise](https://noiseprotocol.org/) pattern that will work.

Comment: What I understand from the question is a protocol that doesn't use symmetric encryption but instead simply encrypts the plaintext messages using asymmetric cryptography. Problem is that in most use cases encrypt-then-sign is not secure (as the signature can be stripped / replaced), and sign-then-encrypt is tricky because the message + signature will generally not fit into the maximum message size.

Comment: In general, instead of designing a new protocol, you could also take an existing protocol and strip all the overhead (e.g. you can assume the versions - except maybe for a single byte - algorithms, key sizes etc.).